# how to share a initialize function between two init functions in Swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

I am used to writing a shared `- (void) initialize` function to handle both `initWithFrame` and `initWithCoder` functions in Objective-C.

However, in Swift I don't seem to be allowed to call a function to do that before calling `super.init()` and also not after that, since the properties need to be initialized before that.

I think writing a `initWithFrame` is not that important anymore but what if I have a custom class with multiple init methods that I want to simplify by using a shared initializer?

Before super.init():

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {        
    self.initialize()//use of self in method call initialize before super.init()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)    
}
```

After super.init():

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {        
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.initialize()//property not initialized at super.init call
}
```

`

Comment: @vadian has your answer. You can also break down the "shared" pieces into what is needed *before* initializing the superview and after. While not a single line of code (or function) it does simplify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the stored properties to be initialized.

For example you could assign a default value to the properties

```
class Foo {

   var name = ""
   var age = 0

   let formatter : DateFormatter = {
       let df = DateFormatter()
       df.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
       return df
   }()
}
```

or use implicit unwrapped optionals

```
class Foo {

   var name = String!
   var age = Int!

   var formatter : DateFormatter! 

}
```

In both cases all properties are initialized and you can first call `super` and then the initialize method. However the first way is recommended for type safety reasons.

Anyway the rule is:

- All non-optional properties must be initialized **before** calling super and `self` can be only used **after** calling super

Comment: Yes, I settled on that indeed. Just set the default values for the properties in the property declarations, and then handle everything else in the shared method after `super.init()`. Thanks.